# Is there a way to wrap word when overflowed? Meaning fit most words as possible before it wraps to new line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a long mathematical expression like so :

```
<div>
   "SUM( FIRST_ARG, SECOND_ARG, AVG( THIRD_ARG ) / MEAN( FOURTH_ARG) )"
</div>
```

And also suppose that the containing div width is small such that it overflows after the last letter in `", AVG( THI"`. Is it first possible to break the expression such instead of overflowing and being hidden or being broken up on the overflown letter, that it fits much as words as possible before wrapping. So it turns into

```
<div>
   "SUM( FIRST_ARG, SECOND_ARG,"  
   "AVG( THIRD_ARG ) / MEAN( FOURTH_ARG) )"
</div>
```

I want to note that the whole mathematical expression is a long string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `word-wrap:break-word`will effectively create new lines when a whole word can't be placed without overflowing. [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ducmzx1p/)

### HTML

```
<div class="math">
   SUM( FIRST_ARG, SECOND_ARG, AVG( THIRD_ARG ) / MEAN( FOURTH_ARG) )
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.math{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width:250px;
}
```

Now if you want to split the string in specific words that's another issue, and JavaScript should be implemented :)

Comment: Nice. I was using similar thing but I guess using <span> instead of div caused some display differences that I didn't expect. I'll build of this. Thanks. One question is that it breaks on underscore characters when I have a variable name `SUM_OF_AVG`, it could potentially break in on of the underscore, but the whole thing is a word. Is there a way to have it recognize underscore is part of a word?

Comment: Sorry, not without scripting, since css it's not a programming language, but a default set of commands :)